# How to prove if vectors are non-redundant, they are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to prove if vectors are non-redundant, they are linearly independent. It just sounds natural to me, but I do not know how to prove it. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the definition for _non-redundant_?

Comment: Indeed, non-redundant is not a proper notion in standard linear algebra.

Comment: The colloquial meaning of "no repeats" wont do, as the vectors $e_1, e_2, (1,1)$ have no 'repeats', but they are not linearly independent.